# Injecting JQuery into Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, language-translation

I am working on a project to translate a webpage and displaying it in an android app.
I have successfully done this by injecting Javascript into webview android using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{

    String jap = "お問い合わせ";
    String eng = "Contact Us";

    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
            "var jpf = '"+jap+"';" +
            "var jp = new RegExp(jpf,'g');" +
            "var en = '"+eng+"';" +
            "document.body.innerHTML = " +
            "document.body.innerHTML.replace(jp,en);" +
            "})()");
}
```

However, this is a very ineffective method, because it would search for each term and replace it. Because of this, I tried to do something similar with jQuery's dictionary:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{    
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript (function(){" +                    
    "var myDictionary = {" +
    "jp : {" +
    "'お問い合わせ' : 'Contact Us'" +
    "}" +
    "}" +
    "$.tr.dictionary(myDictionary);" +
    "$.tr.language('jp');" +
    "var tr = $.tr.translator();" +
    "alert(tr('お問い合わせ'))" +
          "})()");
}
```

This does not seem to work. Please help.

NOTE: I am planning to fill up the dictionary with more words than one. For the first code, I have made a loop that changes the variables `jap` and `eng`, but it is inefficient. I chose not to include that code to increase simplicity. Thanks

Comment: You will have better luck if you explain what "this does not seem to work" means.

Comment: Doesnt work = nothing happens

Comment: @JohnOlsen: You don't use `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: ...` in your jQuery code snippet. If you have that in your real code, no wonder nothing happens.

Comment: Still nothing happens. Is it even possible to put jquery code when injecting javascript?

Comment: Is the jQuery library script already injected into the page? I mean, the page should have `<script src="jquerypath">`. Otherwise, you should inject it using `.loadUrl("javascript:...")`.

Answer (score -1):

Straight from the source: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted#enable_javascript

Enable JavaScript

WebViews don't allow JavaScript by default. To run a web application in the web view, you need to explicitly enable JavaScript by adding the following lines to the onCreate method:

```
// Enable Javascript
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I have already done this. That is y when I use a javascript code, it works perfectly fine

Comment: @JohnOlsen have you found any solution to this ?